# I cannot login to dba.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, login, openid, feedback

I cannot login to dba.stackexchange.com as https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28279/fulproof using my GMail account (having logged into GMail account as the only account in a browser)

When I click login on dba.stackexchange.com, I see for a moment at the top of webpage:

[image: Welcome back]

and then I am again unlogged-in from dba.stackexchange.com.

Tried from IE and Mozilla Firefox, in vain.

I even do not know how to log-in another way than logging-in into GMail and then to login to SE sites!

Update:
Recently I was posting there from another (my job/office machine) but as far as I remember I have shut down it for this weekend.  And now I am trying to log-in from my home PC.

Windows 7 in both.

And, as you can see, I was logged in without problems into SO and MSO sites.

**Update2:**
I've tried password recovery and had successfully set my password but I do not even see how I can log-in using that password!
I am just continuously redirected from any log-in options...

Comment: If it's a database error, the catch-22 will bring the entire network down.

Comment: But I see the answers, [for example this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59941),  of logged-in users more recent than I am having problems. So, others do not have the same problems?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've set my password with password recovery wizard. Then signed off from GMail account (фаеук which I have been stopped continuously redirected from login options)  and managed to log in with my StackExchange account (Email+password)